# не работает ShowHelp с keyword

Tags: c#, winforms, chm

Доброго.
Код вызова хелпа:

```
Help.ShowHelp(this, @"file://D:\NewProject.chm", "SECONDTOPIC");
```

или без префикса:

```
Help.ShowHelp(this, @"D:\NewProject.chm", "SECONDTOPIC");
```

хелп создаю в Help&Manual, ставлю якорь "SECONDTOPIC". Компилю хелп, пробую открыть в коде - получаю:

```
Не удается отобразить эту страницу
Убедитесь, что веб-адрес //ieframe.dll/dnserrordiagoff.htm# правильный. 
Найдите страницу с помощью поисковой системы. 
Обновите страницу через несколько минут.
```

Поиски приводят к непонятным постам про обновления KB917607. Почитал - в исправлениях указаны другие виды ошибок. Поскольку я не хозяин на своей машине, нужно админам дать более полную информацию, коей не обладаю.

Comment: Куда ж ушла целая эпоха chm...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решение оказалось довольно простым, опишу для потомков.

в методе

```
Help.ShowHelp(this, @"D:\NewProject.chm", "SECONDTOPIC");
```

последний аргумент должен содержать не просто ID якоря, но и имя странички, на котором находится.

Вот этот пример работает 100%:

```
Help.ShowHelp(this, @"D:\NewProject.chm", HelpNavigator.Topic, "Second_topic.htm#SECONDTOPIC");
```

Т.е. в "разобранном" виде chm-файл содержит страничку Second_topic.htm, на которой есть элемент с ID=SECONDTOPIC. При компиляции chm-ник не теряет этих свойств и обращение с ним такое же как с любым другим URL-каталогом.